# Allow mass import of Accounts and Contacts only using Data Loader

Tags: data-loader, data-import

I have created a Permission Set and added the "API Enabled" permission, and 'Import Leads' permission.

Is there a way to allow the user with this permission set to only do mass import of Accounts Contacts and Leads Only, and not mass import Opportunities and also prevent this user from mass exporting records from SAlesforce via Data Loader.

I don't want a user Mass Importing Opportunities using Data Loader

Please note that, this user has CRED permission to Opportunities.

Thanks !

Comment: Note that the standard database terminology is CRUD, which stands for Create, Read, Update, and Delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, users don't need the Import Leads permission to use the API for Leads. This permission refers to the Setup UI feature Data Import Wizard. Second, an API integration defines what it can do through its Connected App, and that app is configured to have full access to data. Anything the user can do manually, they can do through the Data Loader. What you'd want to do is to create a [Login Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_login_flow.htm&type=5) that detects if they are using the Data Loader, and if not, assign a [Session-Based Permission Set](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_sets_session_use.htm&type=5) to grant access to Opportunities or other data. Their base profile should not grant CRUD permissions to objects you don't want them to access.

Answer (score 0):

You do have an option to do this by only using [XL-Connector Team Player](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-enabler/) plug-in for Excel.
It allows saving specific mappings in a spreadsheet linked to only specific documents. Then this template works as a data loading app for users who only have access to objects/fields that the admin enabled in the template. Thus you can allow mass uploading some data, but stop the users from uploading other data by banning any other data loading app on the Salesforce end.